# How to check if a String is a valid name for a FrameworkElement in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my code I'm assigning a String to the [name property of a FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx). This String is automatically generated from another part of the application and represents methods name in Java source code and therefore I want to check if it contains a valid name.

Currently I'm doing it that way:

```
        private string getValidName(String s)
        {
            return s.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("#", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("$", "").Replace(" ", "");
        }
```

But the problem is that I don't know which letters I have to replace. For example in this code [ and ] are missing as I found out when I was hit with an Exception.

So my question is. Is there a list of allowed symbols? And if yes how can I implement this in a reasonable way?

Comment: http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/identifiers.html

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I'm note sure if this really can help me, since for example $ seems to be valid character in Java but I can't use it for the name property of the FrameworkElement in WPF.

Comment: Obviously, I was confused by this sentence: "represents methods name in Java source code": Java or WPF? :-)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Sorry for that. The problem is. The String that I use to set the Name Property contains Java method Names.

Comment: IMHO, the most pragmatic way would be to replace everything that is not [a-z][A-Z][0-9] with an underscore and additionally put an underscore in front. With this, you can change any arbitrary string into a valid identifier.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Hmm yes that would be most simple. So I think the simplest way to achieve that is a Regex?

Comment: Yes, I think a Regex will be the way to go than.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, the most pragmatic way would be to replace everything that is not `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` with an underscore and additionally put an underscore in front. With this, you can change any arbitrary string into a valid identifier.
I know that this doesn't exactly answer your question, but I think it is still worth thinking about it.

You can achieve this with the following code:

```
var result = "_" + Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "_");
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good. I'm not really good at Regex so do you know how such a regex should look like?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: `var result = "_" + Regex.Replace(input, @"[^[0-9a-zA-Z]]*", "_");`

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Wait a moment. This doesn't quite work as it should. It won't replace the opening square bracket in `a8.923()/&%.As[d]`. I need to check it, not quite sure, why it is happening.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid potential duplicates, I would also consider replacing each occurence of an invalid character with something unique, for example, its hexadecimal representation in the UTF-8 encoding:

```
Regex.Replace( s, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]",
               m => {
                      var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( m.Value );
                      var hexs = bytes.Select( b => string.Format( "_{0:x2}", b ) );
                      return String.Concat( hexs );
                     } );
```